# How to format edge labels in Graphviz?

Tags: python-3.x, plot, graphviz, dot

I created a `graphviz` plot to visualize a decision tree. Now I would like to add labels (e.g. `True`, `False`) to the graph on all edges.

I was using regex to manipulate the `.dot` file, adding the labels `True` and `False` manually. Resulting in the following file

```
digraph Tree {
node [shape=box, style="rounded", color="black", fontname=helvetica] ;
edge [fontname=helvetica] ;
0 [label="s5 smaller
or equal to 0.0"] ;
1 [label="bmi smaller
or equal to 0.0"] ;
0 -> 1 [labeldistance=2.5, labelangle=45, headlabel="True"] ;
3 [label="value = 110.6"] ;
1 -> 3 [headlabel="True"] ;
4 [label="value = 161.0"] ;
1 -> 4 [headlabel="False"] ;
2 [label="bmi smaller
or equal to 0.0"] ;
0 -> 2 [labeldistance=2.5, labelangle=-45, headlabel="False"] ;
5 [label="value = 174.0"] ;
2 -> 5 [headlabel="True"] ;
6 [label="value = 237.7"] ;
2 -> 6 [headlabel="False"] ;
}
```

This produces the following plot:

[image]

However, the labels don’t get nicely arranged (the arrow cuts-off the label) and I would like to format the text accordingly. Is there a way this can be done in `graphviz` plots?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[A more complete (and messy) answer]
There are multiple levels of label formatting:

- You can insert spaces to influence X position
- you can insert actual newlines or **\n** to influence Y position
- you can use **\l** and **\r** to force left or right justification
- you can use (pseudo) **HTML** strings to add more formatting combinations
- or you can explicitly set X and Y position by setting or modifying the **lp** attribute of a node or edge.

see:

- https://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/attrs.html#k:escString
- https://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/shapes.html#html

for explicit positioning

- https://www.graphviz.org/faq/#FaqDotWithCoords
- https://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/attrs.html#d:lp  (ignore the "write only comment)

Examples:

```
digraph labels {
  a [label=a]
  b [label="b\n\n\n"]
  c [label="       c"]
  d [label="d\n\nD"]
  e [label=<<B>e</B>>]
  f
  r [label=<<table><tr><td>r</td></tr></table>>]
  s
  
  a->b [label=a123]
  b->c [label="b123\n\n\n b321"]
  c->d [label="       c123"]
  d->e [label=" d123\n\nD123"]
  e->f [label=<<I>  e123</I>>]

  r->s [label=<<table><tr><td>r123</td><td>6</td></tr><tr><td></td><td>r321</td></tr></table>>]
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can finesse label placement by adding spaces to the label text, like so:

```
digraph Tree {
node [shape=box, style="rounded", color="black", fontname=helvetica] ;
edge [fontname=helvetica] ;
0 [label="s5 smaller
or equal to 0.0"] ;
1 [label="bmi smaller
or equal to 0.0"] ;
0 -> 1 [labeldistance=2.5, labelangle=45, headlabel="True"] ;
3 [label="value = 110.6"] ;
1 -> 3 [headlabel="True  "] ;
4 [label="value = 161.0"] ;
1 -> 4 [headlabel="False  "] ;
2 [label="bmi smaller
or equal to 0.0"] ;
0 -> 2 [labeldistance=2.5, labelangle=-45, headlabel="False"] ;
5 [label="value = 174.0"] ;
2 -> 5 [headlabel="True  "] ;
6 [label="value = 237.7"] ;
2 -> 6 [headlabel="False    "] ;
}
```

Giving:
[image]

Comment: thanks for the answer! This implies that formatting labels is not really supported. For example, I couldn't move a label in y direction?